# Create a spring bean only once even though called multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have two applications communicating with each other. When the user is authenticated in the 1st application, we want to pass the user context to the other one.

I want to create the user context for the other application and pass the same to the application but i want to limit the user context creation to only once. Can this be achieved by specifying `scope="singleton"` ? Only thing is i will have to do this programatically since, my bean will only be instantiated once the first application authenticates the user.

All my services will be calling the 2nd application from the first application and i want to ensure that the user context (spring bean) for the 2nd application is created only once.

Secondly, when a session time-out happens, i will have to freshly create the user context for the 2nd application.

Can someone guide me on this ?

Comment: How is the 2nd application called? Does the 1st application start it and call methods on it? Is it running in a separate JVM and called via remoting?

Comment: 2nd one is called via remoting. 2nd application is running EJBs on app server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd want to pass the user context bean itself but exchange some sort of token. Spring uses SAML for single sign on, maybe take a look at that: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html